# jQuery Button Change Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written the following code, when you click on the button the whole style will be changed.

```js
$(".Button1").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('Button1Changed');
});
```

```css
.Button1 {
  background-color:#000000;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.Button1Changed {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="Button1">Button 1 - Click</button>
```

But now I need to add some new buttons, like the code below. I want that when I click the "Button 2", the styles of the "Button 1" again changes to the first class! Or when I click on the "Button 3", the style of the button 2 changes again & ...

How can I do it ?!

```js
$(".Button1").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('Button1Changed');
});
```

```css
.Button1 {
  background-color:#000000;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.Button1Changed {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="Button1">Button 1 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 2 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 3 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 4 - Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude current element i.e.`this` using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) from other elements.

```
  $(".Button1").not(this).removeClass('Button1Changed');
```

```js
$(".Button1").click(function() {
  $(".Button1").not(this).removeClass('Button1Changed');
  $(this).toggleClass('Button1Changed');
});
```

```css
.Button1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.Button1Changed {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="Button1">Button 1 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 2 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 3 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 4 - Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be based on [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/): toggle the classes of the current element and the last changed button:

```
$('.Button1.Button1Changed').add(this).toggleClass('Button1Changed');
```

```js
$(".Button1").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.Button1.Button1Changed').add(this).toggleClass('Button1Changed');
});
```

```css
.Button1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.Button1Changed {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="Button1">Button 1 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 2 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 3 - Click</button>
<button class="Button1">Button 4 - Click</button>
```